# How to get a url path in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

The current page url is `http://localhost:8080/operator/list.html`. Ajax in this page should be `http://localhost:8080/operator/somerequest.html`
if `ctx = "http://localhost:8080/operator/"` then ajax would work, but I would like to replace it with thymeleaf builtin notations, so how to do this? I have tried `var ctx = [[${#httpServletRequest.getContextPath()}]]` and `var ctx = [[@{/}]]` and even the sum of this two, but no...

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var ctx = ?; // what thymeleaf annotation
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

I have read [this](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html).

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you really should be using relative urls.  Assuming your application's context is /operator, the thymeleaf generated url should be:

```
var url = [[@{/somerequest.html}]];
```

This will give you the correct url of `/operator/somerequest.html`.  When calling ajax (e.g. `$.post(url)`), the localhost:8080 is assumed.  As far as I'm aware, thymeleaf doesn't provide any capability to get the "localhost:8080" part of the url.